# How to load extra column information into braintree settlement report?

Tags: magento2.2

I want to add extra 2 columns into braintree settlement report after Existing Report Columns currently we have override **braintree_report.xml** file & show extra columns but load information after filter the report

First column as **payment method** from **sales_order_payment** table

Second column as **credit card type** from **sales_order_payment** table

Can we help me how to load the extra columns information?

Answer (score 0):

we have created custom module & created below files.

**app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/braintree_report.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="braintree_report_columns">
        <column name="creditCardType" class="Namespace\Module\Ui\Component\Report\Listing\Column\CreditCardType">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Credit Card Type</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
</columns>
</listing>
```

**app/code/Namespace/Module/Ui/Component/Report/Listing/Column/CreditCardType.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
Namespace\Module\Ui\Component\Report\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Braintree\Model\Adapter\BraintreeAdapterFactory;
use Magento\Braintree\Model\Adapter\BraintreeSearchAdapter;

/**
 * Class CreditCardType
 */
class CreditCardType extends Column
{
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    private $braintreeAdapterFactory;
    /**
     * @var BraintreeSearchAdapter
     */
    private $braintreeSearchAdapter;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        BraintreeAdapterFactory $braintreeAdapterFactory,
        BraintreeSearchAdapter $braintreeSearchAdapter,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->braintreeAdapterFactory = $braintreeAdapterFactory;
        $this->braintreeSearchAdapter = $braintreeSearchAdapter;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {

        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {

            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                $transactionId=$item['id'];
                $braintreeAdapter = $this->braintreeAdapterFactory->create();
                $collection = $braintreeAdapter->search([$this->braintreeSearchAdapter->id()->is($transactionId)]);

                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $collection->firstItem()->creditCard['cardType'];

            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }

}
```